# CharConversionException while transforming xml file

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have a Java program which process xml files. When transforming xml into another xml file base on certain schema( xsd/xsl) it throws following error.

This error only throws for one xml file which has a xml tag like this.

```
<abc>xxx yyyy “ggggg vvvv” uuuu</abc>
```

But after removing or re-type two quotes, it doesn’t throw the error.

Anybody, please assist me to resolve this issue.

java.io.CharConversionException: Character larger than 4 bytes are not supported:  byte 0x93 implies a length of more than 4 bytes
at .org.apache.xmlbeans..impl.piccolo.xml.UTF8XMLDecoder.decode(UTF8XMLDecoder.java:162)

```
<?xml version= “1.0’ encoding =“UTF-8” standalone =“yes “?><xyz xml s=“http://pqr.yy”><Header><abc> aaa “cccc” aaaaa vvv</abc></Header></xyz>.
```

Comment: The answer is in the trace itself. The name is larger than 4 bytes which is not allowed

Comment: Then where I need to check? What kind of change I need to do for xml file?

Comment: It seems that your xml file is not UTF-8 encoded, but Windows-1252. In Windows-1252 the `“` character is encoded as 0x93, and 0x93 is not the start of a valid UTF-8 multibyte sequence

Comment: share your xml code

Comment: No source file is based on UTF-8

Comment: Sorry, due to security reasons of the client, I’m unable to show you the xml. This is just the format of the caused files

Comment: edit your question and put the xml in it and update it

Comment: The `“` character would be encoded in UTF-8 as 0xE2 0x80 0x9C. If it is encoded as 0x93 the file is not UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

As others have reported in comments, it has failed because the typographical quotation marks are encoded in Windows-1292 encoding, not in UTF-8, so the parser hasn't managed to decode them.

The encoding declared in the XML declaration must match the actual encoding used for the characters.

To find out how this error arose, and to prevent it happening again, we would need to know where this (wannabe) XML file came from, and how it was created.

My guess would be that someone used a "smart" editor; Microsoft editors in particular are notorious for changing what you type to what Microsoft think you wanted to type. If you're editing XML by hand it's best to use an XML-aware editor.